# How do I move the x labels to the left but move origin label to the right?

Tags: positioning, pstricks, labels

See below for the code that generates the image below.  How do I move the x labels out of the way to the left, but move the zero to the right?

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1,yunit=0.2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.75,-12)(7,17) 
\psaxes[ticks=y,Dx=2,Dy=10]{->}(0,0)(-1.7,-12)(5.9,13)[$t(s)$,0][$x$,90]
\psxTick(0){0}
\psline[linecolor=blue](-1,0)(0,0)(0,10)(2,10)(2,-10)(4,-10)(4,0)(5,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can position the x-labels horizontally via the `xlabelOffset` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=1,yunit=0.2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.75,-12)(7,17) 
  \psaxes[ticks=y,xlabelOffset=-0.2,Dx=2,Dy=10]{->}(0,0)(-1.7,-12)(5.9,13)[$t(s)$,0][$x$,90]
  \psxTick(0){~~~0}
  \psline[linecolor=blue](-1,0)(0,0)(0,10)(2,10)(2,-10)(4,-10)(4,0)(5,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

In this specific case, with an `xunit=1` (1cm) and `Dx=2`, `xlabelOffset` amounts to `-0.4cm`. As such, you can use

```
  \psxTick(0){\hspace{0.4cm}0}
```

to provide an equivalent right-shift for the tick at the origin.